# In Mathematics, is there a multivariable graphic?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

Assume, function $f(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)$ is given.

> $$f(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)=3^{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5}-3^{n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5}-3^{n_3+n_4+n_5}-3^{n_4+n_5}-3^{n_5}-1$$
>    Here, $\left\{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5 \right\}\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Can visual graphic be set for this function?

For example,

A) for  $\left\{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5 \right\}≤k,k\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$

B)  for $f(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)≤k, k\in\mathbb{Z^{+}}$

I want to see the distribution of the numbers visual.

Is it possible?

In Mathematics, is there a multivariable graphic?

In which mathematics software can I do this?

Can you suggest similar graphics to me?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 2):

You would need six dimensional space to draw a picture of this.

You can get some idea of what's going on by fixing all but one of the variables $n_i$ and drawing an ordinary graph showing what happens when you change the unfixed one. Then try fixing a different one and looking at the new picture.

You can do the same fixing all but two. Then the graph will be three dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for answer. In general ,it is possible, Did I get right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if you got it right. It is possible in six dimensions. In two or three you can visualize parts of it in different ways.